# F23 freezes constantly

Tags: fedora

F23 freezes constantly and randomly after I upgraded from F22. It even freezes during install. I don't know whether it is the kernel (happens less often with kernel 4.0) drivers [Intel bay trail graphics], the system (the PC is new so I doubt if it is hardware), etc.

Here's the `sudo journalctl -p err -b -1` readout:

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2015-11-06 21:18:20 GMT, end at Tue 2015-11-10
23:57:25 GMT. --
Nov 10 15:24:39 localhost.localdomain kernel: intel_soc_dts_thermal:
request_threaded_irq ret -22
Nov 10 15:24:39 localhost.localdomain kernel: intel_soc_dts_thermal:
request_threaded_irq ret -22
Nov 10 15:24:48 localhost.localdomain mcelog[781]: Family 6 Model 37
CPU: only decoding architectural errors
Nov 10 15:24:52 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[784]: Failed to
obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had very similar problem: fedora hangs after

```
dnf system-upgrade reboot
```

My solution is:

1. edit grub menu properties, adding `runlevel 3` to line starts with "linux"
2. to use `distro-sync`, not `system-upgrade`:

   ```
   dnf distro-sync --releasever=23
   ```